# XML using in C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I have connected my C# winforms app to SQL Server 2005 where is a column of XML data type.

The C# program is performing the ADD, DELETE, UPDATE and SELECT queries properly,
now the next step is to get the xml which is stored in the database through query in a string which I did successfully and showed in MessageBox,

My problem is that I want the attributes of the xml and values show in the GridView while ignoring the other tags, please help me with running source code cause just refering to the functions doesn't work. thanks.... suppose I execute reader.read(); whats next?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // setData();
        qry = "select ID , Name from xmlTB";
        reader = db.select_data(qry);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show((reader[0].ToString() +reader[1].ToString()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

database connections are in different class but don't worry everything is working just need next step please

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can see some context?

Comment: It's always a **two-step** process: first, retrieve the xml column from the database (you have that code more or less), and secondly, parse the XML into your attributes and their values (I already provided all that code in a previous answer). So where exactly is the problem, the point you're not getting over??

Comment: first i think my question is more then clear if some1 knows the solution instead of voting it down,

Comment: @marc_s: the second part is required but that your answer didn't solve the problem, can you please edit my this code by the solution? now reader contains everything or the xml from the table am stuck in the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select specific values only. Use [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to extract the needed values from the XML you have.

You can use XDocument.Parse to transform the raw data to a query-able object.

For example:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(rawXmlString);

// Iterates through each element inside the XML document
foreach (XElement el in document.Root.Elements())
{
    // Iterates through each attribute in an element
    foreach (XAttribute attribute in el.Attributes())
    {
        // Action here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx but i mentioned before share some code cause advises didn't work with me before i need solution

Comment: Did you look through the MSDN samples for this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx

Comment: yes i did and i am not able to understand it now am so confused!

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a DataTable then reading the data.  If you find an XmlAttribute which does not already have a column in the DataTable, add one, and then create a DataRow and set it's values.

Finally bind the GridView to the DataSource.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string qry = "select ID , Name from xmlTB";
SqlDataReader reader = db.select_data(qry);
dt.Columns.Add["ID"];
while (reader.Read())
{
    string xmlString = reader[1].ToString();
    string id = reader[0].ToString();
    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    //ensure datatable contains a column for each attribute:
    foreach (XElement el in document.Root.Elements())
    {
        foreach (XAttribute attribute in el.Attributes())
        {  
            if (!dt.Columns.Contains(attribute.Name.LocalName))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(attribute.Name.LocalName, typeof(string)));
            }
        }
    }
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    //set each value in the datarow:
    foreach (XElement el in document.Root.Elements())
    {
        foreach (XAttribute attribute in el.Attributes())
        {
            dr[attribute.Name.LocalName] = attribute.Value;
        }
    }
    dr["ID"] = id;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

//Bind the gridview to the datasource:
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
//*The above assumes your GridView is named dataGridView1.
```

Comment: i already have a DB with column ID so whats need of: dt.Columns.Add["ID"]; AND dr["ID"] = id; it giving error that ID doesn't exist in the table!

Comment: We need to add the ID column because DataTable is a database client object - you need to create it dynamically unless you are using a DataAdapter.  You should confirm that ID is a column in the database.  Don't forget to vote up or accept if the answer puts you on the right path.

Comment: You should confirm that ID is a column in the database.